# How do you programmatically get tax rate in magento on product page

Tags: magento

Say you want to programmatically get the VAT tax rate on product page in magento,how do you go about doing this.

Comment: What have you tried, where in code are you stuck? Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way, within the scope defined in the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: I have tried this: $FlatRate = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::FLAT_RATE, $this->getStore());
Mage::helper('tax')->getShippingPrice($shipping).The problem is i don't know what FLAT_RATE is.I have a product,$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId); and its price ($price = $product->getPrice()) .I want to get the VAT rate set in the backend(say 19%),then display product price including tax

Comment: I have to display this price manually on the product page.I don't want to use settings in the backend.

Comment: self::FLAT_RATE = FLAT_RATE constant on your class

Comment: I know that its constant. I am asking what should that constant point to?

Comment: well if it is a constant then it has a pointed value that you can explore and it is asking configuration information by that value

Comment: Simple: $item->getTaxPercent()

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure how to get the tax rate on its own but if you want to print the product including tax, is this what you are looking for?

```
$_finalPriceInclTax = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice(), true);
```

Comment: Note that this will not work if catalog prices are set (in admin) to display *excluding tax*.

Comment: Use this code snippet in product view to show your tax rate cms text: <?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('tax_class_id') ?>
Set the content in CMS.